# RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined . (this problem happened when i wanted to add cloudinary)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cloudinary

I am trying to adding cloudinary . but I do not know why I getting this error .

this is my updateprofile controller

```
// Update User Profile
exports.updateProfile = catchAsyncErrors(async(req,res,next) =>{
    const newUserData = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
    };

   if (req.body.avatar !== " ") {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);

    const imageId = user.avatar.public_id;

    await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(imageId);

    const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.avatar, {
      folder: "avatars",
     
    });
    newUserData.avatar = {
      public_id: myCloud.public_id,
      url: myCloud.secure_url,
    };
  }

  const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, newUserData, {
    new: true,
    runValidator: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  });

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
  });
});
```

and this is my update profile page in my react app

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import "./EditProfile.css";
import MailOutlineIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MailOutline";
import FaceIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Face";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { clearErrors, loadUser, updateProfile } from "../../actions/userAction";
import Loading from "../../more/Loader";
import MetaData from "../../more/Metadata";
import { UPDATE_PROFILE_RESET } from "../../constans/userContans";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";

const EditProfile = ({ history }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { user } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.user
  );

  const {error, isUpdated, loading } = useSelector((state) => state.profile);

  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState();
  const [avatarPreview, setAvatarPreview] = useState("/profile.png");


  const updateProfileSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const myForm = new FormData();

    myForm.set("name", name);
    myForm.set("email", email);
    myForm.set("avatar", avatar);
    dispatch(updateProfile(myForm));
  };

  console.log(avatar);

  const updateProfileDataChange = (e) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = () => {
        if (reader.readyState === 2) {
          setAvatarPreview(reader.result);
          setAvatar(reader.result);
        }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
      if(user){
          setName(user.name);
          setEmail(user.email);
          setAvatarPreview(user.avatar.url)
      }

    if (error) {
      toast.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }

    if (isUpdated) {
      toast.success("Profile updated successfully");
      dispatch(loadUser());

      history.push("/me");
       
      dispatch({
          type: UPDATE_PROFILE_RESET,
      })
    }
  }, [dispatch, error, alert, history, isUpdated,user]);


  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <Loading />
      ) : (
        <>
          <MetaData title="ویرایش اطلاعات کاربری" />
          <div className="updateProfileContainer">
            <div className="updateProfileBox">
              <h2 className="updateProfileHeading">ویرایش اطلاعات کاربری</h2>

              <form
                className="updateProfileForm"
                encType="multipart/form-data"
                onSubmit={updateProfileSubmit}
              >
                <div className="updateProfileName">
                  <FaceIcon />
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="نام"
                    required
                    name="name"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="updateProfileEmail">
                  <MailOutlineIcon />
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="ایمیل"
                    required
                    name="email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>

                <div id="updateProfileImage">
                  <img src={avatarPreview} alt="Avatar Preview" />
                  
                             {/* //input */}
                             <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                    <button
                      class="btnr"
                      title="انتخاب عکس"
                      style={{padding: "10px 8px", right: "-61px"}}
                      name="avatar"

                    >
                      انتخاب عکس
                      </button>
                    <input
                      type="file"
                      title="انتخاب عکس"
                      onChange={updateProfileDataChange}

                    />
           
                </div>
                </div>
                <input
                  type="submit"
                  value="ویرایش اطلاعات"
                  className="updateProfileBtn"
                />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
      <ToastContainer
        position="top-center"
        autoClose={5000}
        hideProgressBar={false}
        newestOnTop={false}
        closeOnClick
        rtl={false}
        pauseOnFocusLoss
        draggable
        pauseOnHover
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default EditProfile;
```

the error comes from backend part or react part. i can not understand even in post man i get this error . I searched in some of questions in stackoverflow company but none of them related to clodinary .

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).